# XNA 2D Character Movement - Per-Pixel Physics

Tags: xna, 2d, collision, game-physics

I want to make an 2D Shooter Game in XNA. The Terrain shall consist of an Bitmap Image which should be used as an collision map. I tried to do some Character Movement, but I failed with the side-collision and walking up slopes. Do you have any Ideas for that?

Comment: Are you re-inventing the wheel by writing a new game engine, or have you looked at something like Farseer Physics? Farseer has built-in texture-to-terrain processors which work pretty well in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [excellent tutorial](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel_transformed) on pixel-perfect collision available on the MSDN App Hub.

Basically what you end up doing is pulling all the information from the texture (via [GetData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197084.aspx)) as an array, and looping through the overlapping pixels in each texture to see if they're both opaque, black, or whatever else you want to use to determine solidity.  It gets a bit more complicated if you need scalable/rotated images, but the tutorial above contains instructions for that as well.

Comment: 4 year later and excellent tutorial is pretty much lost. Maybe it was [this one](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel_transformed)?